# Advantages of using custom classes in custom modules

Tags: kentico

**Introduction**
I'm designing an application using Kentico 11 CMS. Client provided me with this information:

- Big data are expected
- Versioning and workflow would be nice to have but are not mandatory
- Editing interface for the data is needed

**My research**
Based on Kentico out of the box capabilities, I had to decide whether to use *Pages*, *Module classes* or *Custom tables* to store data. I've excluded *Pages* as they are not advised for big data by docs. After some additional reserach I consider *Custom module* to be the best option for me.

Documentation states that:

> *Custom modules:* Workflow cannot be used for your data. Versioning of the stored data is not supported by default.

**Question**
1) Am I able to easily bypass this restriction when using custom classes for the custom module? (meaning versioning and workflow)

2) Is there any collision when defining an interface for editing the data, while using custom classes in custom modules?

3) When defining *general indexes* for searching will there be any problem when using custom classes in custom modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can setup versioning (https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/module-development-versioning-recycle-bin), not workflow. If you need workflow just for publishing, first you can use pages appliaction, then after page is published move the content to custom class.
2. You can use default UI from Kentico or you can create your own.
3. I don't think so, but you can create always custom index if will be something wrong with general